# Why does \cong \dots \cong not work?

Tags: amsmath

`amsmath`'s `\dots` does a pretty good job at auto-detecting which type of commas to use based on tokens after (and I think before) it. However, what baffles me is why `\cong` in particular does not work, although it is a relation similar to `=`, `\equiv`, `\simeq`, etc. Could someone explain? Is this just a bug?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\(a = \dots = b\)\\
\(a \cong \dots \cong b\), what?\\
\(a \sim \dots \sim b\)\\
\(a \equiv \dots \equiv b\)\\
\(a \simeq \dots \simeq b\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \cong is a robust command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly `amsmath` should also change `\cong` like it changes `\sum` and several other kernel commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy{\cong@}{\cong}
\renewcommand{\cong}{\DOTSB\cong@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(a = \dots = b\)

\(a \cong \dots \cong b\)

\(a \sim \dots \sim b\)

\(a \equiv \dots \equiv b\)

\(a \simeq \dots \simeq b\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So just a bug. Moreover, I would write `\AddToHook{cmd/cong/before}{\DOTSB}`.

Comment: @Gargantuar It wouldn't work, I'm afraid. Try it.

Comment: You're right, but why? If such an interface is offered, I'd trust that it should work (although it is documented that this hook only exists in theory, but might not in practice).

Comment: @Gargantuar `\dots` looks ahead to see whether the first level expansion (if possible) of the next token starts with `\DOTSB` (or `\DOTSI` or `\DOTSX`). But the first level expansion of `\cong` starts with `\protect` and the proposed `\AddToHook` doesn't change it.

Comment: I see, `\AddToHook`, `\NewDocumentCommand`, etc. define robust commands, and they do this by `\protect`ing this?

Comment: @Gargantuar not quite: \AddToHook adds the cmd hook into the payload of the command which is in case of a protected command behind the \protect (if it was defined with \DeclareRobustCommand).

Comment: @egrep could you open an issue for it please?

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Done.